# Webmin - remove file manager bookmarks

Tags: webmin

I have created too many bookmarks in Webmin filemanager using `bookmark this page` link, now when I click on `bookmarks` the bookmarks menu window goes up and hides in browser.
I cannot access bookmarks now, Please suggest me a way to reset bookmarks or a way to delete some of the bookmarks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve bookmarks problem, there is `Module configuration` link in top right of file manager window, I clicked it, and there it was all the bookmarks were listed there, I removed some of the bookmarks so that bookmarks window now fit in available window.
Hope this helps someone with same issue.